# Using Krumo to debug facebook drupal module

Tags: facebook, debugging, drupal, backtracking, krumo

im trying to debug facebook app with krumo, but facebook breaks it (i think he block the script) anyone has success to use krumo with facebook ?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've had trouble outputting through Krumo is some object types; however, most seem to be output just fine. If you're trying to output an unusual object type, that might be it.

Otherwise, can you explain in more detail what you mean by "breaks it"? Does the output not display? Do you get an error? Etc. I can't think of a scenario where Facebook would break Krumo.

Comment: facebook breaks alot of js, its now works fine but jquery plugins is nightmare... can you list a plugins that working good with facebook canvas?